# Can I use the Google Maps API to find out of a house is in a particular town?

Tags: google-maps

I am developing an Estate Agents website. Each property has it's geolocation code saved in a database. Visitors will want to search for properties in a given location (say a town like "Southampton"). Could Google's Maps API (web services) help me with this?

I've seen this facility provided on other Estate Agent's website but I don't know how they do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically a standard "store locator" problem -- except your "stores" are properties. The user enters their search term, say "Southampton"; you geocode that and then find the targets which are within your chosen distance of that location. There are plenty of examples, including in the documentation: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3.html

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I have it all working nicely now after following the eample at the link you gave.

Answer (score 1):

You definetly can. Through Google Maps WebService API you can decode your geolocation into readable address, and the perform a search on it.
If I were you, I'd save locally not only the geolocation, but also the address, better if decomposed in pieces (like Country, Region, City, and so on).
Here you can find the official documentation
http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/apis/maps/documentation/webservices/